# Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, élision, contractions

Peut-on dresser une liste exhaustive de toutes les fonctions que peuvent avoir les mots « de », « d' », « des », « du », « de la », « de le » et « de l' » ?

Une phrase d'exemple est souhaitée pour chacune des fonctions que peuvent avoir ces mots dans une phrase, et une distinction doit être faite entre *de* utilisé en tant que préposition, *de* utilisé en tant qu'article partitif, ou *de* utilisé en tant qu'article dans une phrase négative. Tous les détails sont importants, par exemple le rôle du mot qui suit (parfois contracté) : article défini, pronom ; les règles d'élision et les cas particuliers comme la transformation d'un *des* en *de* devant un adjectif.

Comment: ambitieux projet ! :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Il faut en premier lieu comprendre les phénomènes d'élision et de contraction qui sont à l'œuvre et qui sont indépendants du rôle ou de la nature du mot « de » dans la phrase :

- « *de* » s'élide en « *d'* » devant un son voyelle.
- « *de* » suivi de l'article défini masculin « *le* » se contracte toujours en « *du* », sauf devant un son voyelle où l'élision est prioritaire : on obtient alors « *de l'* ».
- suivi de l'article défini féminin, « *de la* » n'est pas contracté et s'élide aussi en « *de l'* » devant un son voyelle.
- « *de* » suivi de l'article défini pluriel « *les* » se contracte en « *des* », qui hors contexte n'est pas distinguable de l'article indéfini pluriel qui s'écrit et se prononce de la même façon.
- « *de* » suivi des articles indéfinis « *un* » ou « *une* » s'élide selon la règle énoncée plus haut en « *d'un* » et « *d'une* ».
- « *de* » n'est jamais suivi de l'article indéfini pluriel « *des* ».
- « *de* » suivi du *pronom* « *le* » ou du *pronom* « *les* » ne se contracte pas (deux exemples : *n'oublie pas de le faire* ; *il a hâte de les rencontrer*).

On peut à présent s'intéresser aux différentes fonctions grammaticales de « de ». On peut en distinguer quatre :

- **Préposition** (suivie ou non d'un article) qui est généralement attachée à un verbe ou à un nom. Voici quelques cas simples :

  > Il vient *de* repartir.   [*préposition verbale + infinitif*]
  > Il rêve *de* la pluie.    [*préposition verbale + article défini féminin (la)*]
  > Il parle *du* passé.      [*préposition verbale + article défini masculin (le)*]
  > Il a peur *des* serpents. [*préposition verbale + article défini pluriel (les)*]
  > Ils discutent *de* matchs de foot. [*préposition verbale, l'article indéfini pluriel (des) est omis*]
  >
  > Le chien *de* Jérôme.  [*préposition nominale + nom sans déterminant*]
  > La voiture *d'*un ami. [*préposition nominale + article indéfini masculin (un)*]
  > Le jardin *du* voisin.  [*préposition nominale + article défini masculin (le)*]
  > La lumière *des* étoiles. [*préposition nominale + article défini pluriel (les)*]

  Lorsqu'il s'agit de la caractérisation d'un nom, la préposition n'est souvent suivie d'aucun article. Cela permet de préciser de quel type d'objet on parle.

  > Un plan *de* bataille.
  > Une souris *d'*ordinateur.
  > Un château *de* cartes.
  > Un amateur *de* voitures.
  > Un carnet *d'*adresses.

  Le groupe introduit par la préposition peut aussi être libre dans la phrase :

  > *De* son point de vue, il fait beau. [*préposition libre + déterminant possessif (son)*]
  > *De* Paris à Londres, il n'y a qu'un pas. [*préposition libre + nom sans déterminant*]
- **Partitif** (certains composés *du* et *de la* sont appelés « articles partitifs »)

  Les articles partitifs, suivis du singulier, introduisent des quantités indéterminées de matière ou de concepts indénombrables.

  > *Du* sable est entré dans la maison. [*partitif masculin*]
  > Je veux *de l'*eau [*partitif féminin*]
  > Aie *de la* patience ! [*partitif féminin*]
  > Ce projet a *de l'*avenir. [*partitif masculin*]

  On remarquera que lorsqu'un complément est déjà introduit par une *préposition* « de », le partitif disparait entièrement :

  > Ils ont besoin *de* farine. [*préposition, le partitif (de la) est omis*]
  > Ils vivent *d'*air pur et *d'*eau fraiche. [*préposition, le partitif (de l') est omis*]

  Au pluriel, « des » est à la fois l'article indéfini et l'article partitif, aucune distinction syntaxique n'est faite. Il s'agit d'une quantité indéterminée de choses dénombrables, ou dans le cas du partitif de choses indénombrables néanmoins considérées plurielles (*des vivres*, *des ténèbres*, etc.). Qu'il soit article indéfini ou article partitif, après une préposition *de* il disparait (comme dans l'exemple des matchs de foot donné plus haut).
- **Partitif pour une absence**

  *De* est utilisé pour décrire une absence après une négation. Il est dans ce cas aussi appelé « article partitif » :

  > Il n'y a plus *de* pain.
  > Nous ne voulons pas **d'**ennuis.
  > Il ne faut pas faire *de* fautes.
- **Forme courte de l'article indéfini pluriel *des*** (suivi d'un adjectif qui précède le nom)

  Dans la langue soignée l'article indéfini *des* est remplacé par *de* lorsqu'un adjectif s'intercale entre l'adjectif et le nom.

  > Elle a de longs cheveux.
  > De grands efforts seront nécessaires.
  > Ce sont de braves gens.