# Correction de « à coté de le tien »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles, contractions

Dans le dialogue suivant:

> [Nordine] : Moi je suis Algérien, et toi?
>   [nabil] : Moi je suis d'un pays qui est à coté de le tien.
>   [nabil] : Je suis mauritanien.

Est-ce que le morceau "qui est à coté de le tien" est correct?

Comment: **Avertissement** je ne suis PAS français, donc il se peut que j’aie tort, mais je crois qu’on dit plutôt « à côté du tien ».

Comment: Il faut entendre « ... à côté du tien. », en français  *de le* se contracte en *du*.

Answer (score 6):

The correct sentence is : Moi je suis d'un pays qui est à coté **du** tien.

In french you always replace

- "à le" with "au",
- "de le" with "du",
- "de les" with "des".

Comment: When *le* is an article *de* followed by *le* is contracted as *du*. If *le* is a pronoun it isn't. As in “Il n'est pas interdit *de le* faire”. Cf. https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869