# Un article après « plus de » et « moins de »

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

Est-ce que l'on utilise des articles définis ou indéfinis après *plus de* et *moins de* ?

Par exemple, avec *beaucoup de* on n'utilise pas les articles indéfinis et partitifs.

> J'ai beaucoup de (l'article indéfini *des* est supprimé) pommes.
>
> Beaucoup des (de + les) arbres qui sont malades vont être arrachés.

Est-ce la même chose pour *moins de* ?

> J'ai moins de (l'article indéfini *des* est supprimé) pommes que lui.
>
> J'ai moins des (de + les) pommes que lui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, la règle est la même dans tous les cas où *de* est utilisé en tant que préposition. Ça fonctionne de la même façon lorsque *de* suit un nom, un verbe, ou un adverbe comme ceux qui t'intéressent ici (*beaucoup de*, *peu de*, *moins de*, *plus de*).

Pour les règles elles-mêmes, plus de détails ici: 
[Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Dans le deuxième exemple, on ne s'attend pas à un article défini après « plus de » ou « moins de », surtout si la spécificité des pommes n'est pas mentionnée. On dit normalement « J'ai plus de pommes que lui ». Utiliser l'article défini est possible, mais plutôt inhabituel, dans certains cas où la caractérisation est explicite. Comme par exemple dans « J'ai gardé plus des pommes que nous avions récoltées que lui ».

Answer (score 1):

Dans ton exemple, on utilise *des* quand le nom est sujet d'un verbe ensuite (les arbres **vont être arrachés**).

Le fait que tu utilises plus ou moins ne change pas grand chose. Je n'ai pas trouvé de phrase utilisant un verbe après "plus" ou "moins", mais dans ce cas on utiliserait *des*.

Dans ton exemple, la phrase correcte est bien "*J'ai moins de pommes que lui.*"

Comment: En anglais c'est la même chose : "*I have many _ apples*" and "*Many of **the** apples are have are ripe*"

Answer (score 1):

Pour le cas de ta question, la forme valable est en effet "j'ai moins **de** pommes que lui".

Cependant cette règle n'est pas toujours valable, notamment dans le cas où "un" est vu comme le nombre "1".
Par exemple:

> J'ai beaucoup d'une pomme pour mon repas.

Est correct (même si vieilli). Cela signifie: "Une pomme pour mon repas me fait un gros repas".

En utilisant "plus de" (le contraire de "moins de), on a des exemples plus usités:

> Plus d'un touriste s'est fait prendre à ce piège.

Et pour "moins de" également:

> Il me reste moins d'un euros dans mon portemonnaie.