# Why it's 'de' not 'du' in 'une station de taxi' ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, articles

As far as I understand that "de" is used to give more information.
And "de + le" = "du".

so why it's 'de taxi' not 'du taxi' ?

PS : I am not sure if I picked up the right question tags.

Comment: _De_ is quite complex as it can be a preposition or an article and can be contracted. See [this](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869/176) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Une station de taxi* is not dedicated to a single taxi, there are plenty of potential taxis that might use it so that can't be *du taxi* (i.e. *de **le** taxi*).  If you are in a small village where there is a single station for a single taxi, you might say ***la station du taxi***.

It is not either *une station des taxis* because *station* is preceded by an indefinite article, an indefinite *station* is unlikely to be the one of specific *taxis*, however, *la station des taxis* is technically possible in the latter case, e.g. ***la station des taxis de banlieue***.

Finally, as you are talking about a *station* dedicated to *taxis*, the preposition *de* is used. It introduces a relationship between a concrete noun (*station*) and a generic collective (*taxi*). This construction uses no article (a.k.a. *article zéro*), thus ***une station de taxi***.

Comment: Can we say it's the same than when saying "taxi rank" in English, and not "rank for the taxi"? Or even "nourriture pour chien" ("dog food") instead of "nourriture pour le chien" (food for the dog")?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Yes. in English, "taxi rank" or "rank for taxi operators" which is using "article zero". "*Nourriture pour chien*" is also doing it.

Comment: technically "une station du taxi" can make sense if we are talking about a special taxi which stops in several stations. Each of these stations would be "une station du taxi" (one of the stations of the cab)

Comment: @AnneAunyme Yes, it makes sense if such a taxi exists. I would probably say "l'une des stations du taxi" though.