# Pourquoi on dit « au nom de Dieu » ?

Tags: morphologie

Si on dit **au nom *du* roi** (ou **au nom *du* peuple**), pourquoi est-ce qu'on dit **au nom *de* Dieu** ?

C'est parce que *Dieu* dans ce contexte n'est pas précédé par l'article défini *le* ?

Si oui, pourquoi n'est-il pas précédé par l'article défini *le* ?

Si oui, *de*, est-elle une préposition ?

Comment: Même qu'en anglais. The Judeo-Christian deity is simply named "God", not "the god". Of course, wondering why a common noun became a proper noun in this instance could be an interesting question on its own, perhaps for a religion StackExchange. (It certainly goes back at least to biblical Hebrew, in which *'elohim*, one of the two most common names for God, is a homonym with—wait for it—"gods".) Whether this transposition took place independently in languages like French and English or was modelled on religious texts' usage would be an interesting line of inquiry.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Indeed it would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans l'expression : « au nom de Dieu », *Dieu* est considéré comme un nom propre, et en tant que tel, prend une majuscule et n'est donc pas précédé d'un article défini. 
De la même façon on dirait :

- au nom de Zeus.

Si *dieu* est utilisé comme nom commun, en le définissant par exemple, on le fait précéder de l'article défini.

- au nom du dieu Zeus.
- au nom du dieu des Grecs.
- au nom du dieu de miséricorde.

Dans l'expression « au nom de » *de* est bien une préposition. Sur les emplois de *de* voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/358).