# Issue with “de” in verbs

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

How can I know with which verbs DE is contracted and with which ones it isn't?

I mean when we use

> Penser de

We contract DE:

> Je pense de la vie

When in :

> Etre dingue de qn/qch

We don't contract DE :

> Je suis dingue de voyages

Also, why do we say “gain de temps” and not “gain du temps”?

Comment: *Je pense de la vie* is not correct. You can say *Je pense à la vie* or *Ce que je pense de la vie*. And we say *gain de temps* because it means *gain of time* and not *gain of a time*

Comment: Why gain du temps means gain of A time? A time is in French un temps.

Comment: Your question isn't really about verbs (as you note below jcm's answer). The contrast you're asking about can show up whether or not verbs are involved. Unfortunately, the rules about it are very detailed and hard to put into few words. [Here](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)'s a thread that might give you a good start.

Comment: @user10544 did you read my comment ? I said it does NOT mean gain of A time...

Answer (score 1):

The verb *penser* can be used in its transitive form or the intransitive one.
Intransitive :

> Je pense à la vie, à l'univers et à toutes ces étoiles.

The transitive form is more complex and the verb can be used for different meanings but speaking about "de" :

> Je pense de lui que c'est un abruti

just means *I think he is stupid* : je pense **de** *quelque chose* **que** *quelque chose*:

> Je pense de la vie que c'est de la merde.

About *être dingue de*, it's just like *être fou de* etc. when you want to express that you **love** *voyages*, *chocolats* etc.
You can say :

> Je suis dingue à Lyon

to express that when you are in Lyon you become crazy.. Why not ? :)
You also can say :

> Je suis fou des chocolats de chez Bernachon à Lyon.

Finally, *gain de temps* or *gain en temps* refers to the gain *you* can enjoy, *de* qualifies your gain.  But *gain du propriétaire* refers to the gain of the proprietary of your apartment. You can say :

> Le chien de couleur rouge
>   Le chien du voisin
>   Le chien des Baskervilles

Comment: Yes but I dont mean here the Verb Penser. I have a problem with DE. Which verbs has du de la and which dont. Why we say je suis dingue de voyages and not je suis dingue des voyages?

Comment: As noted by luke, the general answer is complicated. There are some rules and many exceptions. The verb *penser* may give you some some simple hints and tracks (???) to follow. Hope this helps. Sorry for my english...