# Why is there no article in the phrase, "assez d'argent"?

Tags: articles, de, absence-d-article

I've grown accustomed to there almost always being an article before nouns, even if that article is contracted with another word. I know that there are exceptions, such as proper nouns and negations. But I didn't expect there to be an exception in this sentence.

> Si tu avais assez d'argent, voyagerais-tu?

I would have expected to see the partitive article: either *du argent* or *de l'argent*. Why is the article lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've likely already encountered “beaucoup de” or “peu de” used without an article many times. “Assez de” is similar, but unlike the former I don't think it can ever be used with an article.

“De” is a preposition in these constructs and the partitive (*du*, *de la*, and even the indefinite plural *des*) is [always omitted after it](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de). You can think about other cases like:

> Il a besoin d'eau.
>
> Il parle de moments difficiles.

Answer (score 1):

Some other examples:

> recueillir **un maximum d**'informations
>
> **une poignée de** données non confidentielles
>
> envoyer **un grand nombre de** photos

As you can see, words that denote a ***quantity***, such as "assez / suffisamment / beaucoup / maximum / poignée", to name but a few, have a noun immediately follow "de" without a definite article in between.