# Why is it "place", not "places" in a sentence: "J'ai assez de place."?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pluriel

According to [this Duolingo forum](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/677030), the translation of this English is the following:

> I have enough room.
>
> J'ai assez de place.

However, I don't understand why it is NOT *places*. The noun is put after *assez de ~*, so I think there should take plurals, since *enough* implies there is more than one.

So why is it *place*, not *places* in this sentence?

Comment: "I have enough rooms" is *j'ai assez de chambres/pièces* while *j'ai assez de places* would be "I have enough seats/spots/positions/..."

Comment: I'll add that "*place*" can be countable or uncountable, and the meaning varies a little. For example, "I have enough parking spaces" is "*J'ai assez de **places** de parking.*"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as in English nouns in French can be mass nouns, countable nouns and other sorts. In this particular case the English syntax is the same, as "room" is uncountable as well as "place" in French; so, you can't have a plural as it is a mark of countable nouns; once you understand that you must keep in mind that the syntax differs in the way that the adverb is connected to the mass noun; for that part of the question see [this answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/27824/17649) and [this other one](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/17649) (**partitifs indéfinis**).