# When to / not to use "de l'aide" / "d'aide" + other nouns like this

Tags: prépositions, articles, de

I feel like my French is pretty good now, but I constantly get tripped up by when and when not to write:

- *de l'aide / d'aide*,
- *d'experience / de l'experience*,
- *plus de X ...*

etc.

Example sentences I don't get the difference between:

> *Tu as besoin **de l'aide**.*
>   *Tu as besoin **d'aide**.*
>   *Tu as besoin **d'expérience**.*
>   *Tu as besoin **de l'expérience**.*

I just never know when it's right or not.  Please help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual form would be the ones without the article:

> *Tu as besoin d'aide*: you need help
>
> *Tu as besoin d'expérience*: you need (to have some) experience

You would use the form with an article when the complement is defined:

> *Tu as besoin de l'aide de ton professeur*: you need your teacher's help
>
> *Tu as besoin de l'expérience d'un vieux routier*: you need the know-how of an old-timer.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed, thanks! So SOME vs SPECIFIC

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a "rule" because both could be correct but one will always sounds more natural than the other depending on your phrase. I've maybe find a way to know wich one to use.
Try to ask the questions `de quoi ?` and `quoi ?` instead of the word where you have a doubt.

For examples :

`J'ai besoin de plus d'expérience -> j'ai besoin "de quoi" ?` - you ask `"de quoi"` so you use `"d'"`. However `Il me faut de l'aide -> Il me faut "quoi" ?` - you ask `"quoi"` so you use `"de"`.

I'm not sure it works every time but it may help you to understand when you use "de" or "d'"

Hope I've help you !

Comment: Thanks, but it was more d'XXX vs de l'xxxx, the l'.  I've updated my question!