# Why is "des", not "de", in "tous les mardis et mercredis des deux mois"?

Tags: grammaire, articles, nombres, contractions

[In the following sentence](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/10127565):

> Tous les mardis et mercredis **des** deux mois.

This is the translation from the following sentence:

> Every Tuesday and Wednesday of both months.

However, according to a comment there, *des* here is a contruction of *de les*, which I have already learned.

But I thought it is fine not to add the article in this case, as *deux* can work as an article. So I wrote the following sentence, which got rejected:

> Tous les mardis et mercredis **de** deux mois.

I wonder, why is the article *les* needed here? I thought if you use a number before a noun, the article is not needed. For example:

> J'ai quatre livres.
>
> Cinquante-deux personnes travaillent dans l'entreprise.

Comment: In English, "Every Tuesday and Wednesday of both months" and "Every Tuesday and Wednesday of two months" mean different things ... the first refers to some particular two months, while the second is indefinite. I'd guess the situation is equivalent in French

Comment: "Every Tuesday and Wednesday of both months." will be translated by "Tous les mardis de chaque mois."

Comment: @BaptisteGavalda If you want to use *chaque*, that should be *tous les mardis et jeudis de chacun des deux mois*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Comment: What's this business of checking everyting in DuoLinguo over here?  Can't you just stick to one forum?  Don't get me wrong, I love DuoLinguo (in other languages) but I don't see why we should function as a sub-forum over here

Comment: @GeorgeM I didn’t check everything, why do you think I checked EVERYTHING? The question is clear enough to be answerable irrespective of any sites. And you won’t get any answers in Duolingo anymore, and the quality of answers is much higher here as well. Also I don’t see why it is OK to ask about a content you see in your textbook but not about a content you see in other websites.

Comment: Because you're asking several questions a day.  You should be hiring a tutor :-)

Comment: @GeorgeM When did I ask several questions a day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article "le" is needed because it is necessary to determine which months you are talking about; as preceding your phrase there must be an introduction of those two month, "le" stipulates they are the months you are talking about; "le" is here used in its determinative function.

- They'll have to participate to a two month training stage in a foreign land and so for not one day of **both** months will they be able to be home, is that clear?
  *Il devront participer à un stage de formation de deux mois dans un pays étranger et donc il n'y aura pas un seul jour **des** deux mois où il puissent être chez eux, est-ce que c'est compris ?*

There is no article in English because it is already present in the word "both"; "both" is a determiner defined as meaning "the two ".

In a different context, you do not use the article.

- Every day **of two months** in the year they spent at a sea resort, I think it must be July and August.
  *Tous les jours **de deux mois** dans l'année il sont dans une station balnéaire, je crois qu'il s'agit de juillet et aout.*

There is no specification of the months before the utterance, they do not belong to the context, and thus no determiner is needed and plain "de" is enough.

You must realise that numbers are considered as adjectives in French ("deux" is a "adjectif numéral cardinal", "deuxième" is a "adjectif numéral ordinal"), never as articles (in one of your sentences : "'deux' can work as an article").

Comment: Ah yes thank you for the last note. I was confused with it.

Answer (score 2):

Duolingo translation is correct.

Using *both* means this is about two specific months, we know which months they are (*les deux mois*). A definite article is required in French.

*De deux mois* would mean, "Every Tuesday and Wednesday of some couple of month".