# De versus du/de la/de l'/des

Tags: grammaire, expressions

I understand that with words of quantity like '***beaucoup de***', the '***de***' stays the same.

But I'm confused as to when I should write just '***de***' or '***du/de la/de l'/des***', if I have a phrase like ***"[noun] de/du/de la/de l'/des [noun]"***.

For example:
Le chat ***des*** enfants. Le chat ***de l'*** enfant.

versus

Mon mode ***de*** vie. Une épidémie ***d'*** obésité.

Comment: I'm afraid that's already been answered [(duplicate)](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/17649).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Answer (score 2):

For this example, *de* is changed by the noun that follows it. Because it's used for a possession purpose.

> Le chat **des** enfants. Le chat **de l'** enfant

You use *des* because there are multiple childrens, it's their cat.
For the second one, usually, we would use *du* or *de la*.

> Le chat *du* voisin.
>
> Le chat *de la* voisine.

But, because *enfant* starts with a vowel, due to the prononciation, you have to write and say *de l'*.
Because it's kinda hard to pronounce **Le chat du enfant**

For the second example, there's no possession here, just description, so *de* won't change.

> Mon mode **de** vie. Une épidémie **d'** obésité.
>
> Une volonté *de* fer. Un mental *d'*acier.

And for the same reason, we use *d'* instead of *de*, when it's followed by a vowel.