# de+le n'égale pas du

Tags: grammaire, articles, contractions

> La Grèce a servi **de** laboratoire pour étudier les effets des politiques
>   d'austérité.

Pourquoi dans certains cas de+le n'égale pas du?

Comment: Ou bien 'de' + 'le' ne donne pas 'du' ou bien l'article 'le' est simplement absent. Essayez de remplacer 'laboratoire' par un mot féminin.

Answer (score 6):

Comme *se tromper de* et *changer de*, ***servir de*** n'est jamais suivi d'un article. Il n'y a pas d'article devant laboratoire et donc pas de *du*.

On peut cependant utiliser ***se servir de*** et dans ce cas, l'article est présent :

> *Pour étudier les effets des politiques d'austérité, l'Europe s'est servie **du** laboratoire qu'a été la Grèce.*

Références:

- [*L'article zéro*, Jean-Michel Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-zero-2.html)
- [*Cas d’absence d’article en français : difficultés des
  apprenants et proposition d’une analyse unifiée*,
  Lidia Lebas-Fraczak](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00749285/document)

Voir aussi: [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Comment: Merci beaucoup!!

Comment: Et la cause de décès? Pourquoi cette règle est appliquée aussi dans ce cas? C'est parce que cela est utlisé comme un terme, et ne se réfère pas à un décès concret?

Comment: On peut trouver *la cause **du** décès*: concerne quelqu'un en particulier, *la cause **des** décès*: celle qui a causé la mort de plusieurs personnes précises et *la cause **de** décès*: ce qui cause des décès en général (ex: la première cause de décès dans le monde est ...)