# Pays de Galles: is "Galles" a plural?

Tags: accord, pluriel, noms-propres

- For the purpose of the question [How and when was the name "Pays de Galles" constructed in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40421/3728) - itself linked to:

  - [When was the name of Wales first mentioned in Romanian, and in which form?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34254/when-was-the-name-of-wales-first-mentioned-in-romanian-and-in-which-form) and to
  - [Excepting Romanian, was “Wales” ever translated/transliterated in modern times outside English with the same term as that meaning “Gaul” or “Gauls”?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/excepting-romanian-was-wales-ever-translated-transliterated-in-modern-times-o))
- I need to know whether *Galles* (as in "Pays de Galles") was constructed as a plural for the name of the people or as a singular, as transliteration from Wales, name of the country;
- Given the original ["Wales" means the people](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/519120/70248)
- and the fact that "Galles" seemed to have meant "Gaulois" (Gauls) - https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/galles - click *third* tab **"GALLES, subst. masc. plur."** — look for `Galles, subst. masc. plur.Synon. de Gaulois.Les Galles (...) avaient les pieds fort plats (Senancour, Obermann, t. 1, 1840, p. 100).`)

[NOTE: not really: that passage in Senancour seems rather an one-instance occurence, a droll improvisation.]

- considering comments under that question saying that "Galles" is a plural in French

[NOTE: not a plural like Pays-Bas though: see note *en bas*.

**my question is:**

- is `Galles`, as in "Prince de Galles" a plural in French?

### Note:

**By "plural" I mean: does it have in French a plural connotation in any form? Clearly, it is not a plural like in *Les Pays-Bas* (where *Pays* is plural), but is it something like *Ardennes***?

I would personally say NO, because otherwise we would have *des* instead of *de*, like in *"le royaume **des** Pays-Bas"* - but I want to know for sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a plural like in *Les Pays-Bas* but something like *Ardennes*?" The singular *Ardenne* is  used  in French along with the plural form for the region, only the administrative area (*département*) is in always plural.

Comment: We will say here: "les Ardennes SONT ceci-cela" (subject is "LES Ardennes"), but "la région des Ardennes EST ceci-cela", because the subject here is "LA région".

Comment: @dralpuop **Subject** is a grammatical function. When you say [*Le point culminant de l'Ardenne est situé en Belgique...*](http://ardenneaparis.free.fr/AAP_savoir1.htm) *région* is clearly **not** the subject. When you say [*l'Ardenne est une région boisée...*](https://www.larousse.fr/encyclopedie/autre-region/Ardenne/106031) Ardenne **is** the subject, not *région*. Just as you would say *Les Hauts-de-France **sont** une région du nord de la France* because Hauts-de-France is plural.

Answer (score 6):

After some research, I may be able to clarify some points.
It appears that, yes, Galles is a noun that represents a plural noun, as you showed before with the cnrtl definition.

However, you need to know that this word is part of some nouns that are only used with a plural form, and it has no singular form.
It appears this kind of unvariable nouns are called "plurale tantum" from its own latin word (I couldn't find any french translation for this, and it appears to be the same for all languages). More informations [here](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plurale_tantum).

And finally, the reason why it is called *Pays de Galles*, and not *Pays des Galles*, is because this small detail changes everything.
In French, the part *De Galles* is what we call a ["Complément du Nom"](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compl%C3%A9ment_du_nom).

Saying *Des Galles*, would mean that this country belongs to the Galles (or the Wales, as a group of people). Sometimes, *des* is used as a part of a "Complément du nom" to express a relation of  possession  to some persons or some things.
But, using the word *de* instead of *des*, would mean something different than *belonging to*. It would then signify that there is some things or some persons in this place, but not with the idea of belonging.

That particular aspect would be found with something such as *Bande de brutes*, and *Bande des brutes*. Here, the first case means that this is a group of people made up of rude fellows in general. But saying *Bande des Brutes*, would mean that this is a group that is under the commandment of some people called Brutes, the Brutes being rude people or not. And the truth is, this little detail can change lots of things when you use it.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: Pays de sauvages, pays de voleurs, pays de fous, pays de montagnes, pays de Flandres et aussi : les Galles des Nord, les Galles du Sud...

Comment: @jlliagre: Galles des Nord? Really? Do you have a name of place or country with 'des' ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. That should be *Les Galles **du** Nord*

Comment: [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=les+Galles+du+Sud+%2B+les+Galles+du+Nord%2Cla+Galles+du+Sud%2Bla+Galles+du+Nord&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28les%20Galles%20du%20Sud%20%2B%20les%20Galles%20du%20Nord%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28la%20Galles%20du%20Sud%20%2B%20la%20Galles%20du%20Nord%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm granting the bounty, but not marking the answer as definitive,

Answer (score 4):

In *pays de Galles*, *Galles* is not the name of the people, or at least, it hasn't been perceived that way any time since 1800. Since this question was motivated by the question of whether the Romanian name for Wales, *Ţara Galilor* (literally *Country of the Gauls*, or *Pays des Galles*) was a mistranslation, and this name first appeared in the 19th century, the answer to that question is that it was indeed a mistranslation.

To see this, look at the name of New South Wales, Australia,  in French. It has been variously rendered as *Nouvelles-Galles du Sud* and *Nouvelle-Galles du Sud*. But if *Galles* meant *Welsh* and not *Wales*, it would have undoubtedly been *Nouveaux-Galles du Sud.*  See [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nouveaux-Galles+du+Sud%2C+Nouveaux+Galles+du+Sud%2CNouvelles+Galles+du+Sud%2CNouvelle+Galles+du+Sud%2CNouvelles-Galles+du+Sud%2CNouvelle-Galles+du+Sud&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNouvelles%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelle%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelles%20-%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelle%20-%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CNouvelles%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelle%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelles%20-%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNouvelle%20-%20Galles%20du%20Sud%3B%2Cc0).  French would not use a feminine plural as the name of a people (save for *les Amazones*). Google does find a few references to *Nouveaux-Galles du Sud* on the internet, but there are almost none in Google Books.

Interestingly, the Ngram shows that while most people treated *Galles* as a singular in *Nouvelle(s)-Galles du Sud*, there was a substantial minority that treated *Galles* as plural. This was most prevalent between 1880 and 1960, but it goes back to the 1790s, only a few years after the Colony of New South Wales was founded. [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle-Galles_du_Sud) says that according to Australia, officially *Nouvelle-Galles du Sud* should be singular, which may account for the decrease of the form *Nouvelles-Galles* after 1960.

Answer (score 1):

"Galles" is a proper noun, which are not due to respect rules of orthography : in French, we say "les noms propres n'ont pas d'orthographe".

Here, le "Pays de Galles" is like le "Royaume des aveugles" (meaning a country which contains blind people, or Wales people, or fairies and goblins) is singular: "le pays" remains the subject of the verb, not the people living inside it.

Comment: Les noms propre n'ont pas d'orthographe??

Comment: La façon dont ils s'écrivent n'est pas tenue de respecter les règles de l'orthographe.

Comment: Ça ne veut pas dire qu'on n'est pas tenus de respecter la façon dont ils s'écrivent :^)

Comment: Il serait plus exact de dire qu'il n'y a pas de règles pour les noms propres mais qu'ils ont une orthographe fixée par l'usage.

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question qui demande plutôt si dans « Pays de Galles » le **s** à « Galles » est un **s** de pluriel.

Comment: "les noms propres n'ont pas d'orthographe" est un proverbe français, autant que je sache.

Comment: "Galles" est la traduction de quasi littérale de "Walles", c'est un nom propre et en tant que tel, la règle du singulier ou du pluriel ne s'applique pas. En fait, on conjugue le verbe en fonction de ce qu'on va mettre devant le nom, depending on ce qu'on essaie d'exprimer dans la phrase. Que ce soit "les Galles sont ceci-cela" ou "la Galles est ceci-cela".

Comment: Jamais entendu ce proverbe pour ma part. Mais on voit bien que l'orthographe des noms propres est fixée, à l'exception peut-être des translittération d'autres alphabet (nom russes ou arabes par ex.) qui peuvent varier.