# Has any 19th century author used the term "Galles" for "Gauls" except Étienne Pivert de Senancour in "Obermann"?

Tags: traduction, lexique, dictionnaires

Asking other questions ([How and when was the name "Pays de Galles" constructed in French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40421/how-and-when-was-the-name-pays-de-galles-constructed-in-french)) I found from a comment (see username in last part of that question) about an entry from a 19th century dictionary mentioned at the Centre National de Ressources Textuelles et Lexicales website ([here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/galles), and there click *third* tab **"GALLES, subst. masc. plur."**)

> Galles, subst. masc. plur.Synon. de Gaulois.Les Galles (...) avaient
>   les pieds fort plats (Senancour, Obermann, t. 1, 1840, p. 100).

which suposedly mentions ***Galles* as a synonym of *Gauls***

The sentence is: "*les **Galles** ou Welches avaient les pieds fort plats, et les Francs les avaient fort élevés*"

The text online accessible [here](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Obermann) and [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32808).

> LETTRE XXVIII. Paris, 27 février, III.
>
> Vous ne pouviez me demander plus à propos d'où vient l'expression de
>   pied-plat. Ce matin, je ne le savais pas davantage que vous; je crains
>   bien de ne le pas savoir mieux ce soir, quoiqu'on m'ait dit ce que je
>   vais vous rendre.
>
> Puisque les Gaulois ont été soumis aux Romains, c'est qu'ils étaient
>   faits pour servir; puisque les Francs ont envahi les Gaules, c'est
>   qu'ils étaient nés pour vaincre: conclusions frappantes. Or, les
>   Galles ou Welches avaient les pieds fort plats, et les Francs les
>   avaient fort élevés. Les Francs méprisèrent tous ces pieds-plats, ces
>   vaincus, ces serfs, ses cultivateurs: et maintenant que les
>   descendants des Francs sont très-exposés à obéir aux enfants des
>   Gaulois; un pied-plat est encore un homme fait pour servir. Je ne me
>   rappelle point où je lisais dernièrement, qu'il n'y a pas en France
>   une famille qui puisse prétendre, avec quelque fondement, descendre de
>   cette horde du Nord qui prit un pays déjà pris que ses maîtres ne
>   savaient comment garder. Mais ces origines qui échappent à l'art par
>   excellence, à la science héraldique se trouvent prouvées par le fait:
>   dans la foule la plus confuse on distinguera facilement les petits
>   neveux des Scythes[21], et tous les pieds-plats reconnaîtront leurs
>   maîtres. Je ne me ressouviens point des formes plus ou moins nobles de
>   votre pied; mais je vous avertis que le mien est celui des
>   conquérants: c'est à vous de voir si vous pouvez conserver avec moi le
>   ton familier.

I have found it free on Google Books [here](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Obermann.html?id=Q2oPvIcaAjoC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=galles&f=false):

[image]

I haven't read the whole Romantic epistolary novel just yet. Although at least that part is rather comical and the whole argument there is a joke, that doesn't *necessarily* mean that the use of the term is improper or fantastical. But it *might* be so — especially as it appears only once in the book; the second time it has a different meaning, `la principauté de
Galles, du pays de Vaud` inside a footnote that says:

> Le mot  Vaud  ne veut point dire ici vallée, mais il vient du Celtique
>   dont on a fait Welches: les Suisses de la partie allemande appellent
>   le pays de Vaud  Welschland . Les Germains désignaient les Gaulois par
>   le mot Wale; d'où viennent les noms de la principauté de  Galles , du
>   pays de Vaud, de ce qu'on appelle dans la Belgique pays  Walon , de la
>   Gascogne, etc.

It could be that the author improvises or is joking and, because the character as well as the writer lived in Switzerland, the terms involved here ("Galles ou Welches") are just Swiss region names of Celtic origin that the author jokingly applies to *the* Gauls - *à la légère*. - In this case "Galles" is used for "Gauls" (people of *Gallia* in Latin) just because the name of the "principauté de Galles" also "comes from" the same word as  "the Gauls".

**Was that use common? In which period? 
How frequent was that use in the 19th century?**

---

I am interested in this also in connection with a different question — [on the translation of *Wales — Pays de Galles* — in Romanian.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34254/when-was-the-name-of-wales-first-mentioned-in-romanian-and-in-which-form): coincidence or not, the name of Wales/Pays de **Galles** is literally translated in Romanian as "Country/Land of the **Gauls**"!

---

Note that I (just like the author of *Obermann*) am fully aware of [the common origin of all the terms involved here - the old German root naming foreigners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walhaz). Galles/Wales, Welsh, Gallois, Gaulois, Waloon, Wallachian, etc have the same root, but obviously very different meaning.

It might be that Étienne Pivert de Senancour took advantage of that loose connection between different terms when he wrote that text: which would explain the use of the term *in case it is **not** a common one*. But I don't know *that* yet, and that's what I'm asking.

Comment: You might be interested in this paper [*Les métamorphoses du nom des Gaulois*](https://www.persee.fr/doc/bsnaf_0081-1181_1999_num_1996_1_10103) if you haven't rad it yet. And in [*Histoire des Gaules, et des conquêtes des Gaulois, depuis leur origine jusqu'à la fondation de la monarchie françoise*](https://bit.ly/2R08vgx) (published in1752) we can read: *Pourquoi les Romains se font-ils avisés d'appeller Galles ou Gaulois les Celtes, contre la règle générale observée ...*

Comment: On the original question: why Wales = Galles, note that W in english corresponds often to Gu/G in French, as in Guillaume/William, Guerre/War (more obvious in Guerrier/Warrior).