# Articles contractés - DES ou DE ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

Bonjour tout le monde,

Je voudrais savoir pourquoi on dit : "dans de très grandes villes", et non pas: " dans des grandes villes" dans la phrase suivante:

﻿﻿Le brouillard est davantage présent hors agglomération. En effet, dans certaines villes ou villages il peut être plus épais que *dans **de** très grandes villes*.

Merci d'avance.

Comment: Quand l'adjectif précède le nom, l'article indéfini *des* change à *de.*  Il y a une bonne explication : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de  mais je ne dirais pas tout à fait duplex.

Comment: Merci Beaucoup, j' ai eu ma réponse.