# Difference between article partitif and indefini

Tags: grammaire

What is the difference, if any, between ***des*** (*article indéfini*) and ***des*** (*article partitif*)?

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de

Answer (score 3):

***Des* as a partitive article**

Partitive articles are employed before a name designating an uncountable reality. It is used in the plural form when no singular form exists for the noun in question.

> - *Cet été, je prendrai **des** [vacances](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vacances).*
> - *Il mange **des** [rillettes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rillettes).*

For those two words, the singular form either don't exist (rillettes) or do not have the same meaning (vacances).

***Des* as an indefinite article**

Indefinite articles are determinants used to refer to something or someone undetermined.

> *Il mange **des** pâtes*.

To avoid confusion, [this site](https://www.jerevise.fr/du-des-articles-partitif-indefini-contracte.html) suggest:

> To avoid confusion between the partitive article "*des*" and the indefinite article "*des*", replace this determinant with "un" or "*une*". If the sentence does not lose its meaning, it is an indefinite article. If the sentence no longer makes sense, but the word "des" can be replaced by "*un peu de*", it is a partitive article.