# Je pique des crises : pourquoi 'des' ?

Tags: de

I read this phrase in a magazine : 'Je pique des crises de nerfs' which I take to mean 'I am afflicted by nervous crises'. I am wondering why it is 'des crises' and not 'de crises' (as it is 'de nerfs' and not 'des nerfs')?

Comment: Because you can have more than one. *Des* is the plural of *un/une.* And in French you can't omit the indefinite article. https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/the-indefinite-article-un-une-and-des

Comment: De in front of *nerfs* is not an article it is a preposition. *de nerfs* is a [*complément du nom*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/36538/637).

Comment: [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869/358)

Answer (score 2):

***Crise de nerf*** is a colloquial expression that is used here in the idiom ***piquer une crise de nerf***.

It is a colloquial way to say "to become suddenly upset, to freak out over something or someone".

Similar idioms are:

> *Piquer une tête*: to dive

> *Piquer un fard*: to blush

> *Piquer un fou rire*: to have an incontrollable laugh

***Des*** is used simply because it is the plural of ***une***, there is more than one crisis. English would uses no article here. (singular: I have a nervous crisis / plural: I have nervous crisis)

***De*** is not used here because it is not the plural of ***un(e)***.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take care of the basic question first; why "crise de nerfs" instead of "crise des nerfs".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/crise)) − Spéc. **Crise de nerfs**. ,,Expression populaire pour désigner des manifestations paroxystiques à caractères neuro-psychiatriques et comportant plus particulièrement des manifestations psychomotrices, et des troubles de la conscience et du comportement`` (Lafon 1969).

You can also find the spelling "crise de nerf"  ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crise+de+nerfs%2Ccrise+de+nerf&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrise%20de%20nerfs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrise%20de%20nerf%3B%2Cc0)), and as well "crise de**s** nerfs", but this latter is comparatively rare ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crise+des+nerfs%2Ccrise+de+nerfs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrise%20des%20nerfs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccrise%20de%20nerfs%3B%2Cc0), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=crise+des+nerfs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccrise%20des%20nerfs%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccrise%20des%20nerfs%3B%2Cc0), [crise des nerfs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crise%20des%20nerfs%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

In this locution there is no article ("des" is  the contraction of "de" (preposition) and "les" (article)) because the semantic relation between "crise" and "nerfs" is one that has been reckoned with as that of kind (sort, type,…) rather than another relation.

You say

- "engorgement des amygdales", "inflammation des yeux, des intestins, des veines, des parties, des tissus, etc."

because the various parts are being affected; it's is different with "crise de nerfs" as the nerves are considered to be the agents of the affliction rather than being afflicted. But there is in this remark no solid principle, and as shows the Google page relative to the use of "des" (mentioned above), people do not go by any such principle.

So, a why has no easy answer, and it is more useful to consider that this is merely usage, and at that, it is changing.

The second question has a complicated answer. As is the sentence, "des" is necessary because "de" in this positive contexte comes through as the preposition "de", and the verb "piquer" is "transitif direct" (has an object introduced by no preposition). Since, the sentence aims at saying that the person is afflicted by a certain number of nervous fits, what is called for is an indefinite article (zero article in English, or "some"). There is just one choice in french: "des".

However, if we change the sentence only slightly by just making it negative, then "de" is the right word.

- Je *ne* pique *pas* ***de*** crises de nerfs.

In this case, we are not dealing with the preposition "de" but with the article "de". This article is necessary  for the negative form. This reference, [Guide de grammaire française  pour étudiants finnophones, l'article indéfini](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#0501), explains that well (never mind the Finish, or the few details concerning it that are in French).

So, in the negative form this is the proper article, but there are exceptional cases of use of the negative form when you have to revert to the usual "des". Those are so called cases of "partial negation" (also explained in the reference above).

- je n'ai pas des crises de nerfs, j'ai des crises de foie. (*the verb "piquer", colloquial, not free of connotations, is unidiomatic for "crise de foie".*)

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful explanation, almost all of which makes good sense to me. However, with regards to 'pique des crises' I had thought 'pique' was an intransitive verb followed by the preposition 'de': I sting ('je pique') due to ('des') crises ('crises'). Is this incorrect ?

Comment: That explains it perfectly. Thank you once again.

Comment: @TomAdair In this context, the verb has nothing to do with its basic sense (to sting). (TLFi : d) Au fig., fam. Avoir un accès soudain (de), éprouver, manifester brusquement une envie de quelque chose, de faire quelque chose. Piquer une colère, une crise de nerfs, un fou-rire, une rage, un quarante de fièvre.)//What could be added for a better understanding of this use of  "piquer" and "crise  de nerfs" is that there are really two meanings for "crise de nerfs";  1/ the medical one which I cite in my answer is not used with "piquer". 2/ Most of the time when people say   (1/2)

Comment: @TomAdair "J'ai piqué une crise de nerfs." and the like, they really mean that they became angry and that for a spell voiced their anger; there is no question of mental illness. Therefore that is another "crise de nerfs". (2/2)