# Ma défense de / des plus faibles

Tags: articles

> ...cette nuit, il a réussi à persuader les autres qu’il ferait un
> meilleur chef de bande. Il s’agissait de la goutte qui a fait déborder
> le vase.  Mes promenades en solitaire, mes lectures, ma défense **de**
> plus faibles.

Est-ce qu'il faudrait employer l'article défini *ma défense **des** plus faibles* = *ma défense **de** + **les**  plus faibles* (les faibles que je connais) ? Ou l'article indéfini *ma défense **de** plus faibles* (ma défense de certaines personnes qui se trouvent parmi les plus faibles) ?

Comment: Je trouve que "*des plus faibles*" est plus adapté. Dans ce contexte, "*de plus faible*" sonne un peu maladroite. D'ailleurs, lire "*la goutte*" sans le "*d'eau*" qui suit habituellement est assez étrange.

Comment: [Après suppression de commentaires] Si quelqu'un souhaite remettre en cause l'existence de cette question, qu'il ou elle n'hésite pas à utiliser le vote "close", disponible sous celle-ci. Merci de rester civilisés dans les commentaires.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Answer (score 2):

Tu peux dire les deux.

*Ma défense de plus faibles*: J'ai défendu des (certains) plus faibles.

*Ma défense des plus faibles*: Je défends les plus faibles (en général ou en particulier, on ne sait pas).

Comment: Une autre nuance est qu'avec "***des*** *plus faibles*", *plus* est un superlatif : on parle des gens les plus faibles de tous. Alors qu'avec "***de*** *plus faibles*" c'est un comparatif : "*de gens plus faibles que moi*".

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Merci beaucoup. J'ai cherché cette expression sur Internet. Il y a quelques sources qui mentionnent _goutte_ sans _eau_, mais oui, la plupart écrivent _la goutte d'eau_.

Answer (score 1):

Tout dépend du contexte, de ce que l'on veut dire. Comme je vois que la grammaire n'est pas tout à fait assimilée (« de » et « des » ne sont pas des articles dans cette expression), je vais rappeler le point vue habituel en ce qui les concerne.

Dans cette construction « de » est une préposition et soit la règle de l'effacement est appliquée (de) soit celle de la contraction (des).

> ([J M Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html#053)) **Influence de la pré­po­si­tion** ***de***
> **Règle d’effacement** : après la pré­po­si­tion *de*, les for­mes **d’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni** commençant par un d ne sont pas exprimées. Les for­mes qui s’effacent  sont
> -- ***des*** (ou ***de*** devant ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé) et
> -- ***du***, ***de la***.

- maison **de** poupées  (*non correct, mais sens voulu* : « maison **de <s>des</s>** poupées »)
- mur **de** longues briques (*non correct, mais sens voulu* : « mur **de <s>de</s>** longues briques  »)
- pile **de** pain (*non correct, mais sens voulu* : « pile **de <s>du</s>** pain  »)
- bouteille **de** bière (*non correct, mais sens voulu* : « bouteille **de <s>de la</s>** bière  »)

Dans la construction dont on s'occupe,

> «  ma défense **de/des** plus faibles »,

il est dans tous les cas nécessaire que la préposition « de » paraisse, cela parce que le type de nom dont « défense » fait partie a un complément prépositionnel (objet) introduit par cette préposition.

- défense **d**'un accusé, défense **de** Pierre, défense **de** ses droits, prise **de** Paris, vol **de** la couronne, traversée **de** la Seine, etc.

Si on utilise « de », comme il n'est pas question d'adjectif antéposé, ni de complément de verbe direct à la forme négative (voir Kalmbach), ce mot ne peut être que la préposition, ce qui laisse « plus faible » sans article (apparemment). Dire cela équivaut à reconnaitre à « plus faible » le statut grammatical de substantif ; on voit qu'il est nécessaire de reconnaitre, du moins partiellement, ce statut. On ne dit pas « ce plus faible », on ne modifie pas « plus faible » par un adjectif, mais la nature de « plus faible » peut être celle d'un adjectif nominalisé ; ces adjectif sont « en partie » des noms.

([ex.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_humeurs_de_la_mer/qOPvK0gQNlwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22un+plus+faible%22&pg=PA236&printsec=frontcover)) Eh bien , Papa , vous me dites que c'est honteux de battre un plus faible. Je suis d'accord. Mais ce n'est pas possible de battre un plus fort. Alors qui voulez - vous qu'on batte ? On se bat entre égaux.

Dans cette construction, en tant que locution adjectivale nominalisée, il est nécessaire que « plus faibles » soit précédé d'un article, qui ne peut être que l'article indéfini « des » supprimé par effacement.

- « ma défense de des plus faibles »

La règle de l'effacement ne change rien au sens et donc la forme normale, « ma défense de plus faibles » est une consruction où « plus faibles » a une nature indéfinie.

Si on utilise « des », comme la préposition « de » doit paraitre, il s'ensuit que « des » est une forme contractée de « de » et de l'article **défini pluriel** (seule possibilité de forme contractée), et non pas l'article indéfini « des ». Donc, « plus faibles » a ici soit une nature déterminée dans le contexte, soit une nature générique (voir les utilisations de l'article défini, en particulier l'utilisation générique, par exemple [la référence générique](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-defini.html#069)).

Comment: Merci, mais je connais cette règle _de = de + des_.  Je l'ai d'ailleurs écrit dans ma question. Par contre, je hésitais entre _**les** plus faibles (les faibles que je connais)_ et _certaines personnes qui se trouvent parmi les plus faibles_. Je ne savais pas si ces _plus faibles_ étaient définis ou non.