# Pour laisser place aux / à de rares carrosses qui nous dépassent

Tags: articles

> Nous descendons en silence ; A. en avant, et je suis derrière lui pour
> laisser place **aux** rares carrosses qui nous dépassent.
>
> Nous descendons en silence ; A. en avant, et je suis derrière lui pour
> laisser place à **de** rares carrosses qui nous dépassent.

Est-ce que ces carrosses sont définis parce qu'ils nous dépassent, ou indéfinis parce que nous les voyons pour la première fois et le fait qu'ils nous dépassent n'a guère d'importance ? Ou cela dépend du point de vue du narrateur comme dans ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/49820/ma-d%C3%A9fense-de-des-plus-faibles) ?

Comment: Oui, le choix dépend du narrateur mais je dirais que le sens est exactement le même entre les deux phrases. Les carrosses en question sont clairement définis même introduits par *de rares*.

Comment: @jlliagre OK, merci !

Answer (score 2):

Il est utile, en plus de la description due à LBU (« L'article défini s'emploie devant le nom pour indiquer qu'il s'agit d'un être ou d'une chose connus du locuteur et de l'interlocuteur (c'est l'article notoire de Damourette et Pichon) »), de considérer la définition plus ample que l'on trouve dans la Wikipédia.

> ([Wikipédia, Article défini](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_d%C3%A9fini)) (gras de user LPH) En grammaire, l'article défini est une sous-catégorie de déterminant défini, qui participe à l'actualisation du nom noyau en indiquant, soit que le référent (la chose, l'animal, la personne dont il s'agit) est connu des actants de l'énonciation, soit que des **satellites** vont suivre (adjectif qualificatif, complément de nom, **proposition relative**…) qui permettront à l'interlocuteur d'identifier précisément ce représenté.

Cela signifie que « aux rares carrosses qui nous dépassent » (à les rares carrosses) implique qu'il y a d'autres carrosses, peut-être de nombreux carrosses et que ceux-là ne dépassent pas le véhicule.

« De rares carrosses qui nous dépassent » signifie que les carrosses ne sont pas nombreux et que tous dépassent le véhicule.

Comment: A. et B. marchent à pied, donc tous les carrosses qui prennent cette route les dépassent. Il n'y a pas de voitures dans cet univers.

Comment: @Oreste Dans ce cas on peut encore penser que les carrosses qui viennent en sens inverse sont compris dans le sous-entendu, c'est à dire que l'on ne se soucie pas de ceux-là.