# Comment peut-on expliquer l'utilisation des prépositions de et des dans le passage suivant?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, de

On m'a toujours dit que

> Nom + de + nom

sert à généraliser

> Exemple : il s'occupe de familles pauvres. (En général)

Tandis que,

> Nom + des + nom

est plutôt utilisé pour spécifier.

> Exemple : il s'occupe des familles pauvres (de son quartier par exemple).

Le problème c'est que je suis tombé sur d'autres phrases où cette logique ne peut plus être acceptée.

Exemple :

> "Il a ordonné également de maintenir l'interdiction stricte de l'importation **des** viandes congelées et d'encourager la consommation **de** viandes locales."

Pourquoi dit-on "de viandes locales" et "des viandes congelées" ? Pourquoi pas "des viandes locales"? "De viandes congelées"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*L'importation* et *la consommation* peuvent tous deux être suivis de *de* (« de des » viandes) ou de *des* (« de les » viandes) sans que le sens en soit affecté.

L'interdiction concerne toutes les viandes congelées (les) ou les viandes congelées qu'on souhaiterait importer (des), ce qui revient au même. De façon similaire, on encourage la consommation de toutes les viandes locales (des) ou de viandes locales non spécifiées (de).

Voir aussi : [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/10869/1109)