# Why "île aux Oiseaux" and not "île d'Oiseaux"?

Tags: prépositions, géographie

In the Arcachon Bay, there is an island called "île aux Oiseaux". I was quite surprised that *aux* is used as a preposition instead of *de* or *d'*. Why is that?

Comment: Also [Île aux Cygnes - Paris](https://www.paperblog.fr/8512318/le-parc-aux-cerfs-ou-le-fantasme-du-bordel-royal/) , [Parc aux cerfs- Versailles](https://www.paperblog.fr/8512318/le-parc-aux-cerfs-ou-le-fantasme-du-bordel-royal/)   or "mare aux canards"

Comment: @Graffito but *Lac des Cygnes*

Answer (score 3):

✔ Although "l'Île aux Oiseaux" became a proper name (as the capital Î and O suggest), "aux" originally means "avec des" in this case.

*~ The island with birds (on it)*.

See https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/au III D. 3. b)

> la chambre nue aux persiennes closes

> les routes aux vieux calvaires

✔ "L'île des Oiseaux" is the contraction of [ île <s>de les</s> Oiseaux ]

*~ island of the birds = these specific birds, definite*

It can be a place name with the same meaning as "aux oiseaux". Similarly, there is an "[île des Faisans](https://www.geo.fr/geopolitique/lile-des-faisans-dans-le-pays-basque-six-mois-francaise-six-mois-espagnole-210789)".

See https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de

> ferme de Rouge-Sel

> domaine des Sept-Pendus

✘ "L'île d'oiseaux" is the contraction of [ île <s>de oiseaux</s> ] and would mean *the island made of birds (indefinite)* which can be a poetic thing but not the meaning we're looking for.

> Au milieu du lac flottait une île d'oiseaux immobiles.

Answer (score 1):

It could not have been <strike>*l'ile d'Oiseaux*</strike> because *oiseaux* is in the plural, if we were talking about a single bird then indeed it could have been *l'ile **de l'oiseau***.

So your question is Why *île **aux** Oiseaux* and not *île **des** Oiseaux*?

Using *de*<sup>1</sup> would imply that the island belongs to the birds, obviously that's not the case. The island is a refuge for migratory birds, it's a place where there are lots of birds, hence its name.

About the use of *de* there's a good answer [there](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/358).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Reminder: *des* stands for *de les*.</sup>

Comment: I don't think _l'ile d'Oiseaux_ would be impossible just because oiseaux is plural?

Comment: *L'Île d'Yeu(x)* ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Lu dans le journal ce matin: _milieu d'affaires_. J'aurais dit _milieu des affaires_, personellement.

Comment: @Frank *[Villes d'eaux](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ville_d%E2%80%99eaux)*, *[L'Île aux enfants](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yovYIJd_NE)*