# When to use "de" and when to use "du/de la/des"?

Tags: grammaire, usage, prépositions

I've been learning French for a few years, but one question has always bothered me, that is, I don't know when to use "de" with articles and when to not. For example, if I wanted to say "responsibility of teachers", as in

> To be a good teacher, you need to understand the responsibilities of teachers.

Should I say:

> ... il faut comprendre les responsabilités **des professeurs**

Or

> ... il faut comprendre les responsabilités **de professeur**

Similarly, I cannot tell the difference between "Les travaux **de l'église**" or "Les **travaux d'église**" when I want to say "the church works(that the pastor has to do)".

Which one is correct and what are the rules?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Je crois que ma question est assez spécifique... si ce n'est pas le cas veuillez m'indiquer comment je peux l'améliorer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tout savoir sur ces combinaisons de petits mots qui contiennent « de »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10869/tout-savoir-sur-ces-combinaisons-de-petits-mots-qui-contiennent-de)

Comment: Not really. I still don't understand the difference between "travail de l'église" "travail d'église". Both seem to mean "church work", but what's the difference.

Comment: In that case limit your question to "travail de l'église" vs "travail d'église", as it stands your question is too broad.  In *travail de l'église* a specific church (building) is meant since there's a definite article.  *Travail d'église*, without the definite article  refers to church wok in general, and most probably (but context needed) church not meant as a building but as the institution.

Comment: @dvx2718 It's not easy for sure, in part because the two expressions overlap in meaning, depending on the context. Both are absolutely correct, usable, and used all the time. "travail d'église" does not have the "article défini" _la/l'_, so it's more suitable to talk about "église" as an abstract organization, rather than to point to a specific church. But unfortunately, if no specific church is present in the context, "travail de l'église" can also be used to talk about church in the abstract ...

Comment: @dvx2718 Re-reading my previous comment, I'm not sure if I'm convinced myself :-) (and I'm a native French speaker). Goes to show this is not easy. It might be better to use something like _le travail d'un homme d'église_ or _le travail qu'on attend d'un pasteur_. This last one maybe rings the best so far. I hope I'm not confusing you more ...

Comment: Don't stick too much to the source language when attempting a translation. None of your French phrases are natural. 1. *Pour être un bon professeur, il faut comprendre les responsabilités liées à ce métier.* 2. *Les activités paroissiales qui incombent au pasteur.*

Comment: Agree with @jlliagre. Also: _Pour être un bon professeur, il faut comprendre les responsabilités de ce métier_ and _Les responsabilités paroissiales du pasteur_ - but those are just minor variations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut dire les deux avec une nuance de sens possible: *des professeurs* peut faire référence à un groupe spécifique de professeurs, par exemple:

> *Les responsabilités des professeurs dans cette école sont enumérées dans ce document.*

ou être plus général ("tous les professeurs"), par exemple:

> *Les responsabilités des professeurs ne sont pas les mêmes que celles du directeur*.

L'expression *de professeur* fait plutôt référence au métier de professeur en général. Par exemple:

> *Pour faire le métier de professeur, on a besoin d'un diplôme d'études secondaires.*

C'est la même chose pour *de l'église*: soit une église en particulier, identifiée dans le contexte, soit "l'église" en général. Mais pour *d'église*, il s'agirait a priori de l'église en général, il n'y a pas la possibilité qu'il s'agisse d'une église particulière. Exemples:

> *Le curé de l'église St Jean est un homme affable*.

> *Cet homme d'église fait partie d'une sorte d'église très traditionnelle.*

Mais aussi:

> *Ce curé fait partie d'une frange très traditionnelle de l'église.*

Answer (score -1):

**I**

> ... il faut comprendre les responsabilités de professeur

You wouldn't say that in this case ;  "responsabilité" has a different meaning, in particular because « de » is used.

- Ce sont des responsabilités de professeur, comme celle qui demande qu'il avertisse le principal lorsqu'il y a des élèves dissipés dans la classe.
- <s>Les responsabilités de professeur dans une classe sont d'abord de veiller à la bonne conduite des élèves, et à tenir le cahier d'appel.</s>
- Les responsabilités d'un professeur dans une classe sont d'abord de veiller à la bonne conduite des élèves, et à tenir le cahier d'appel.
- Les responsabilités des professeurs dans une classe sont d'abord de veiller à la bonne conduite des élèves, et à tenir le cahier d'appel.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/responsabilit%C3%A9)) **B. − P. ext.**, **souvent au plur.** Charge entraînant la prise de décisions importantes et obligeant celui qui en est investi à rendre compte de ses actes et de ses résultats à ceux qui la lui ont confiée.
> • Responsabilité professionnelle; accepter, être investi de hautes, importantes, lourdes responsabilités.
> • Mais M. Daladier, qui, depuis plusieurs années, portait la responsabilité de la défense nationale, avait épousé le système en vigueur (De Gaulle,Mém. guerre,1954, p. 27)
> • À force d'ennuyer un homme, de le bourrer de soucis, de responsabilités, d'obligations, de scrupules, de décisions à prendre, de retours sur lui-même, on peut arriver à l'ahurir et à le ronger tellement, qu'il n'oppose plus de résistance à une volonté, même quand il la connaît mauvaise... Monterhl., Lépreuses,1939, p. 1407.

This means "charge de professeur" (or "fonction de", or "fonctions"), and it is used rather for professors, not teachers.

([Cor à corps ou La Folie d’interpréter: Biographie de Francis ...Éric Bailleul · 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Cor_%C3%A0_corps_ou_La_Folie_d_interpr%C3%A9ter/JtA4EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&pg=PA182&printsec=frontcover))  Sa surprise est grande car il doit s'organiser pour assurer ses cours dans les universités du Delaware et de Philadelphie en même temps que d'assumer ses nouvelles responsabilités de professeur à la Staatliche Hochschule fur Musik

[Fais-moi confiance, tu vas finir par aimer ça! - Angele Loiseau · 2019](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Fais_moi_confiance_tu_vas_finir_par_aime/mIfCDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&pg=PA43&printsec=frontcover)) J'ai repris mes responsabilités de professeur principal, je continue l'option théâtre tout en travaillant l'Histoire et la Géographie avec mes élèves.

([L'éducation des élites en Autriche: les lycées catholiques ... - Agnès Bernard · 2005](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/L_%C3%A9ducation_des_%C3%A9lites_en_Autriche/bHgmAQAAIAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&dq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&printsec=frontcover) ) la formation longue des jeunes prêtres , rallongée encore par l'obligation de passer l'examen universitaire les oblige à entrecouper leurs responsabilités de professeur ou de préfets de temps d'étude et de formation , pendant ...

([Jean-Marie Londeix: Master of the Modern Saxophone - James Umble, ‎Michèle Gingras, ‎Hervé Corbé · 2000](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Jean_Marie_Londeix/E0YIAQAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&dq=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s+de+professeur%22&printsec=frontcover) ) Ses responsabilités de professeur de solfège lui permettent de développer ses compétences et sa sensibilité , ce qui l'aidera tout au long de sa carrière musicale

You can go through the tens of examples on [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22responsabilit%C3%A9s%20de%20professeur%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr) so as to acquire a better notion of this usage.

You can also go through [this page](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22de%20professeur%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr), where other cases of the use of « de » are found for the same function ; that is « de » takes on the function of denoting a type.

responsabilités de professeur (type de charge)
concours de professeur (type de concours)
chaire de professeur (and so on)
fonctions de professeur
réputation de professeur
diplôme de professeur
rang de professeur
charge de professeur
titre de professeur
diplôme de professeur
rôle de professeur
cabinet de professeur
chaire de professeur
poste de professeur
carrière de professeur
emploi de professeur
salaire de professeur
qualité de professeur
place de professeur

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de)) 2. [Dans un compl. déterminatif (genre, espèce)]
> a) […]
> b) [En parlant d'inanimés abstr.]
> • Toutes les fois que la personnalité est opprimée, que la liberté individuelle n'a pas son équitable manifestation, il y a crime de lèse-humanité (Du Camp, Hollande,1859, p. 248)
> • Le roman, entend-on couramment répéter, se sépare actuellement en deux genres bien distincts : le roman psychologique et le roman de situation. D'un côté, ceux de Dostoïevski, de l'autre, ceux de Kafka. Sarraute, L'Ère du soupçon,1956, p. 9.

responsabilités de professeur (type de charge)
concours de professeur (type de concours)
chaire de professeur (and so on)
fonctions de professeur
réputation de professeur
diplôme de professeur
rang de professeur
charge de professeur
titre de professeur
diplôme de professeur
rôle de professeur
cabinet de professeur
chaire de professeur
poste de professeur
carrière de professeur
emploi de professeur
salaire de professeur
qualité de professeur
place de professeur

**II**

you have two choices.

1/  ... il faut comprendre les responsabilités **des** professeurs

2/ ... il faut comprendre les responsabilités **d'un** professeur

In doing so, you speak about those responsabilities that a teacher (any teacher) endorses as part of his function.

In both cases you can do that because you use genéric articles (les (« de les » is always contracted in « des ») , un).

Here « de » fulfills a relationship of possession (responsabilities which are those of teachers)

> (TLFi) 5. La modalité est une appartenance.
> a) Possession, dépendance.
> − [Le compl. déterminatif est déterminé]
> α) [Le possesseur est une pers., un groupe ou un être animé déterminé.]
> ♦ de + subst. abstr.
> • Il y a une chose sur laquelle je n'admets pas qu'on transige... l'honneur de la famille (H. Bataille, Maman Colibri,1904I, 2, p. 5).
> • Je sais que la distraction est un privilège du monde scientifique (Duhamel, Cécile,1938, p. 96).

Notice « de la », « de le », which last one is in fact « du » (contraction, « de le » is never said)

**III**

> Similarly, I cannot tell the difference between "Les travaux **de l'église**" or "Les **travaux d'église**" when I want to say "the church works (that the pastor has to do)".

By "church work" I assume  you do not mean what is in the Merriam-Webster definition below.

> ([merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/church%20work))
> **church work** noun : work in behalf of a church especially in furtherance of its purpose (as in charity, visitation of the sick, or support of the church's world mission)

Instead, I believe that you mean this.

> [Job Responsibilities of a Pastor](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=the+church+works+that+the+pastor+has+to+do)  Your duties include preparing weekly sermons, preaching and conducting worship services. It's your responsibility to interpret biblical scripture for the congregation. You also provide care and counseling to church members and assist them in crisis situations.

In other words you are talking about the ministry

> ((SOED) **ministry**  The functions o a particular function proper or pertaining to a minister, priest, etc.; the action or an act of rligious ministration

That is not a two word phrase in French. It is called "the sacerdoce".

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sacerdoce)) **sacerdoce** A. −,Fonction de ceux qui ont le privilège du sacré ou de certains rapports publics avec la divinité, soit pour offrir les sacrifices et prier au nom du peuple, soit pour transmettre au peuple certains enseignements et bénédictions de Dieu`` (Foi t. 1 1968).

« travail d'église » is not defined; « travail de l'église » can be defined in at least two way (one infml and the other fml) but will not mean what you had in mind, so this second case can't be discussed.

Comment: This answer is not trustworthy - native French speaker here.